# warning: declaration of ‘name’ shadows a previous local

Tags: c++

I have this very simple snippet here:

```
std::string testName;

if (argc < 2) {
    std::string testName = "default";
}
else {
    std::string testName = argv[2];
}
```

For some reason the compiler gives me 2 warnings;

```
warning: declaration of ‘testName’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
   std::string testName = "default";
               ^

note: shadowed declaration is here
  std::string testName;
              ^

warning: declaration of ‘testName’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
   std::string testName = argv[2];
               ^

note: shadowed declaration is here
  std::string testName;
              ^
```

I am feeling rusty and stupid, appreciate the help!

Comment: I counted 2 warnings.  The second `testName` is shadowing the first `testName`.  The third `testName` is also shadowing the first `testName`.

Comment: Do you really want to define a *new* variable with the same name in the nested scopes?

Comment: Well the warning says it all: You have two variables called `testName`, the global one in your first line and the second one (either the one initialized with "default" or argv[2];". Change the name of the outer variable to resolve it.

Comment: `std::string testName = "default";` --- > `testName = "default";`

Comment: And by the way, welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] so you may learn how this community works and get the most out of it.

Comment: @Micha - you miscounted; there's three variables of that name (the second and third both shadow the first).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning you are getting is due to the fact that you are declaring a new variable inside your conditionals. To fix, remove the `std::string` inside the conditionals:

```
std::string testName;

if (argc < 2) {
    testName = "default"; // Prefixing with std::string creates a new variable
}
else {
    testName = argv[2]; // Not doing so assigns the old variable
}
```

If you wanted to do this all on one line, you could do the following with the ternary operator, since initialization could be considered better than declaring and assigning later.

```
std::string testName = argc < 2 ? "default" : argv[2];
```